# Power BI Nesting Hierarchy Indicator to Match Power Pivot

Tags: powerbi, hierarchy, powerpivot

I have a client that is accustomed to seeing hierarchy nesting in Power Pivot using Excel that looks and behaves like this:

[[image: Power Query Hierarchy]]

Specifically, they love the plus/minus expand/collapse functionality.

We are now moving to Power BI which has a different philosophy when it comes to navigating a hierarchy.  However, my client really likes the plus/minus paradigm in Power Query.  Has anyone ever run across this before and come up with a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this is not possible in a matrix visual. It's a very popular request that you can vote for on the [Power BI ideas site](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/9207006-matrix-collapse-expand-buttons) though.

It is possible to do this with a slicer though. I use the [HierarchySlicer](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104380820) custom visual to do this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/765226/alexis-olson do you use this Hierarchy Slicer enough that you could help me with a question offline?

Answer (score 0):

Expand and collapse in matrix visual is coming as Public Preview.

Originally planned for October release, now moved to November.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/business-applications-release-notes/october18/intelligence-platform/power-bi-desktop/expand-collapse-matrix

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/business-applications-release-notes/october18/intelligence-platform/planned-features

Answer (score 0):

You can implement drill down features using +/- buttons in Power BI Matrix visualisation. 
This facilitates an explorer style expand/ collapse navigation by clicking + / -  buttons.  This visualization is also good for Pivot kinda reports.

You can add +/ - buttons to the row headers through the formatting pane under the row headers card. By default, the icons will match the formatting of the row header. Additionally, you can format it with the colour and size.

[image]

Row Header properties of Matrix visualisation

[image]